# 'ssf.dse' Tables in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my SQL Server database, I have a view which uses `ssf.dse.ApplicationLog` and `ssf.dse.applications` tables in the background.

The problem is - I can't find these tables in the database: they are not in the `Tables` folder, not in `Views` folder, or any other folder.

Did I miss something? What kind of tables have `ssf.dse` prefix?

Comment: Please check in the synonyms  under that database . use this `Select * from master.sys.all_objects
where name like '%ApplicationLog%'` to check all objects

Comment: `ssf.dse.ApplicationLog` means: table `ApplicationLog` in the `dse` schema on the `ssf` database - so these tables are in a different database - that's why you're not seeing them in your own database ...

Comment: @marc_s: by the way - what is the purpose of schema? in which cases would be better to use multiple schemas? And are all tables from all schemas stored under 'Tables'?

Comment: A schema can help you organize your tables - if you look at the `AdventureWorks` sample database - tables are organized into schema according to organizational structure - one schema for `HumanResources` and so on. You can also grant permissions based on schema - allow (or disallow) some users access to everything inside a schema

Comment: So it means - we use different schemas for different data marts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssf.dse.ApplicationLog` means:

- table `ApplicationLog`
- in the `dse` schema
- in the `ssf` database

So these tables are stored in a different database - that's why you're not seeing them in your own database ...